# Populating Excel multiple cells with data from Add-in user defined function (UDF)

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, office-interop

I am working on an Add-in for Excel that needs to populate one or more cells in the worksheet with the data from server. I did following:

1. Created an Add-in (xlam) and created the user defined function:
   GetMyData()
2. I am calling this function from a simple Excel Worksheet. In A1 cell, I entered the formula =GetMyData()
3. My server returns JSON Array. I am able to parse the JSON and now trying to populate the A1 and the below rows with values I got from the server. (in this case, I have 20 values, so I want to populate A1:A20 cells).

The issue is that according to Microsoft KB, a user defined function is able to change the value of the active cell only.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/170787/description-of-limitations-of-custom-functions-in-excel
I also tried to run the code below that changes only one cell to a hardcoded value:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("DataSheet").Cells(1, 1).Value = '12312'
```

Still - getting exception.

Could any one assist with this issue?

Comment: Change it to a sub and call it from a button.

Comment: Have the function return a vertical array, highlight all the cells and array enter the formula into all the cells at once.

Comment: You can use an array formula as outlined in the answers below, but you will need to know what the maximum number of returned items can be, so that you can fill the formula into the correct number of cells.  If that can't work in your case then you'd need to find a different approach.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example:

```
Public Function cerial(d As Date)
    Dim bry(1 To 20, 1 To 1) As String
    For i = 1 To 20
        bry(i, 1) = CStr(d) & "_" & i
    Next i
    cerial = bry
End Function
```

It creates an array of 20 items.

There is a tiny trick to using it in the worksheet.

Select, say, **E1** through **E20**.  Then click in the formula bar and enter the array formula:

```
=cerial(TODAY())
```

[image]

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.  If this is done properly, the formula will appear enclosed in brackets in the Formula Bar.

**NOTE:**

In this example, the internal array `bry()` is two dimensional.

Answer (score 2):

Have the function return a vertical array.

For Example:

```
Function GetMyData() As Variant()
Dim test() As Variant
test = Array(1, 2, 3, 4)
GetMyData = Application.Transpose(test)

End Function
```

Then highlight all the cells you would ever need with the top as the active cell.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then put this formula in the formula bar:

```
=GetMyData()
```

And hit Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter to array enter the formula.

[image]

If you choose more than the array returns you will get errors.

---

Or you can, using the Array return, use this to deal with error and enter normally, but it runs the function for each time it is put in a cell.

Put this in the first cell:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(GetMyData(),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

Then copy/drag down till you get blanks

[image]